# awk skip number of lines of large data file but output 10 following before skipping next number of lines

Tags: awk

I have large data file which i need to perform processing on in order to able to handle the file. it is a large file 20 GB and it contain a lot fields around 20 000/per line
what i want to do is to keep the first 10 lines, skip a 1000 lines then keep 10 lines skip another 1000 lines keep 10 lines until the of file. I would grateful for some help on this.

Comment: Does it have to be `awk`? at least with GNU `split`, you could do `split -l 1000 --filter='head -n 10' file` (or `split -l 1010 --filter='head -n 10' file` to interpret your requirement more literally)

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like:

```
awk '((NR - 1) % 1010) < 10' file
```

Comment: this does not seem to work on simple sample file (`seq 1 10000 > testfile`)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest updated. Somehow update yours so I can retract my downvote

Comment: NR -1 does the trick, now it is working =) gives same output as @RomanPerekhrest solution but is easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR<=10 || ((NR % 1010) < 10) {print}' file.txt
```

Comment: Not the most elegant, but it's tested and think it's ok.